# How do I save my mentor?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I'm playing Assassin's Creed Revelations and I'm in a memory of Altaïr. The mission is to try and rescue my mentor by killing the Templar without getting seen, but for some reason I bump into guards everywhere.

**What would be a 'safe' route through the castle to rescue my mentor?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is pretty easy once you know what to look for.  As you enter the castle, on the right, you can actually climb up to the outer wall.  There are only two guards up here, so they should be very easy to take out.  If you continue to follow the path, it'll take you directly above the prisoners, at which point you can easily do an air assassination on your target.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to point out: Those 4 are not in the count for "Saving all citizens" for 100% Synch.

Those can be found in the town (before getting in Masyaf castle) as black dots on your map when you are out of combat.

Comment: i whi the game was clearer about this. i restarted so many times :(